# In C++, std::move_iterator<Iterator>::pointer isn't the same as an iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, llvm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template< typename Iterator>
int test_it(){
    int rv;
  
    rv= std::is_same<
    Iterator,    
    typename std::move_iterator<Iterator>::pointer
    >::value;
    
   printf("point rv = %d\n", rv);
   return rv;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<int> v(5,0);
    
    test_it< decltype(v)::iterator > ();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Using an old version of llvm c++ library, I got

```
point rv=0
```

My question is: should rv be 1?
since std::move_iterator::pointer is an iterator.

Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/adad2df7865ca5b7).  What version of llvm are you using?

Comment: Looks like an [old fixed bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27259) in libc++

Comment: Mike, thanks for sharing it. I guess it is the bug.